# Connecting to an sql server database using php on windows

Tags: php, sql-server

I am facing a problem in connecting to an sql server 2008 database.I have already installed the php extension **php_sqlsrv.dll**.I have also installed the native client 10.0 .The code i am using is :

```
 <?php /* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */
 $serverName = "(xxx.xx.x.xx)";

 /* Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.  */ $uid = "xxxxxx";
 $pwd = "xxxxx"; $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                          "PWD"=>$pwd,
                          "Database"=>"xxxxxx");

 /* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */ $conn = sqlsrv_connect(
 $serverName, $connectionInfo); if( $conn == false ) {
      echo "Unable to connect.</br>";
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); } else {   echo "success";     }                                                                           sqlsrv_close($conn); ?>
```

Also the sql server has an authentication tye :**SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION**.
The above code is giving the following error:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [0] => 08001 
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
            [1] => 53 
            [code] => 53 
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
        ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 
            [1] => 0 [code] => 0 
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
            [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
            [1] => 53 [code] => 53 
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. 
        ) 
    )
```

please Help

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Vazquez-Abrams ya it says it couldnt connect to the sql server... but the server is up and running...

Comment: Did you verify the connection between the two machines?

Comment: You aren't connected to your SQL server. make sure all the connection info is correct.

Comment: @jared ya i am able to access it through my browser.. by typing http://xxx.xx.xx.x and it  opens. i've also enabled remote access option on the server