# Cannot connect with MS SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database using `sqlsrv_connect` in PHP.

I've already installed, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 native client from `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27596` (SQLSRV30.exe), since my php version is 5.4.3 and I am running with Thread Safety enabled.

I've also tried [Connecting to an sql server database using php on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323109/connecting-to-an-sql-server-database-using-php-on-windows).

I've configured everything accordingly, how it should be configured, but `sqlsrv_connect` is still giving me:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

The thing is when I run `php.exe -i` in my command prompt, it shows that `sqlsrv` support is enabled: sqlsrv support => enabled, but it is not showing in `phpinfo()` although the sqlsrv extension is in my php ext directory, what could be wrong?

What am I doing wrong? I need help with this from people who might have had this connection problem before.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was that, I later learnt that there are three `php.ini` files that needs to be modified for the added extension to work.

- The first is: `wamp/bin/php/php.ini`
- The second: `wamp/bin/apache/php.ini`
- The third: `wamp/bin/php/phpForApache.ini`

I didn't edit the last file, that was the problem. It works now.